# How to add XML namespace in Abap Simple Transformation

Tags: xml, transformation, abap-st

I am getting XML from from internal tables using Simple Transformation. This is the output XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Complement>
 <Document Doc="AAA">

    <Locations>             
        <Location>
            <Origin 
                RFC="URE180429TM6"/>            
            <Address 
                Country="SOME_COUNTRY" 
                />
                [....]
        </Location>
    </Locations>
    
    <Products NumTotal="1">
        <Product
            ValorProduct="12164501"
            />
            [....]
       </Product>
    </Products>

    [....]....

 </Document>
</Complement>
```

But now what I NEED to do is to Change some XML ELEMENT Name (rename them)..  which should make my XML looks like this:

For example I need the first Element (Complement) wil looks like  cfdi:Complement (using the Colon `:` between cfdi  and Complement)... etc etc

```
<cfdi:Complement>
  <document:Document Doc="AAA">

    <document:Locations>                
        <document:Location>
            <document:Origin 
                RFC="URE180429TM6"/>            
            <document:Domicilio 
                Country="NIGERIA" 
                />
                [....]
        </document:Location>
    </document:Locations>
    
    <document:Products NumTotal="1">
        <document:Product
            ValorProduct="12164501"
            />
            [....]
       </document:Product>
    </document:Products>

    [....]....

  </document:Document>
</cfdi:Complement>
```

I have been trying to change the Element Names directly from Simple Transformation Code but it´s not working:

```
<?sap.transform simple?>
<tt:transform xmlns:tt="http://www.sap.com/transformation-templates" 
xmlns:ddic="http://www.sap.com/abapxml/types/dictionary"
xmlns:def="http://www.sap.com/abapxml/types/defined">
<tt:root name="COMPLEMENT" type="ddic:ZCOMPLEMENT"/>
<tt:template>
<tt:namespace name="cfdi"/>
<tt:namespace name="document"/>

  <cfdi:Complement>    "<----- I get error from this lines
    <document:Document>   "<----- I get error from this lines
      <tt:attribute name="Doc" value-ref=".COMPLEMENT.DOCUMENT.DOC"/>

      <document:Locations>       
        <Location>            
          <Origin>        
            <tt:attribute name="RFC" value-ref=".COMPLEMENT.DOCUMENT.LOCATIONS.LOCATION.ORIGIN.RFC"/>
              [....]
          </Origin>              
          <Address>
            <tt:attribute name="Country" value-ref=".COMPLEMENT.DOCUMENT.LOCATIONS.LOCATION.ADDRESS.COUNTRY"/>
              [....]
          </Address>                            
        </Location>
      </Locations>

      <Products>         
        <tt:attribute name="NumTotal" value-ref=".COMPLEMENT.DOCUMENT.PRODUCTS.NUMTOTAL"/>            
          <Product>
            <tt:attribute name="ValorProduct" value-ref="VALORPRODUCT"/>
              [....]
          </Product>
      </Products>
      
        [....]....
      
    </Document>
  </Complement>

</tt:template>
</tt:transform>
```

these are the errors i get:

> `undeclared namespace prefix 'cfdi'`

and

> `undeclared namespace prefix 'document'`

This is the Simple Transformation Code:

I just need to change the name of Element. But I didn´t think it is harder than it seems.

Kindly help me on this. I´m new in this Abap World. or any idea will help me so so much. Regards

Comment: Please provide code in a minimal version, we don't need all the stuff. Please show the version of the code which produces the error message. You have to provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use multiple namespaces in single XML element through ABAP Simple Transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43585383/use-multiple-namespaces-in-single-xml-element-through-abap-simple-transformation)

Comment: I have updated my Simple Transformation code and I pointed out where the errors come from.. and I saw you suggested link but it isn´t too clear to me. I´m still trying to get the name changed:(

Comment: The other answer is showing `xmlns:etd` defined at a top position. For instance, you could define `xmlns:cfdi="dummy" xmlns:document="dummy"` in `<tt:transform ...` (instead of dummy, use the URI corresponding to cfdi and document)

Comment: Thanks for answering... In this case I have not URI, or maybe I dont know why should I specify it... Is it necesary just for changing the Element Name? or what is it for?.

Comment: You must have a URI by definition, or "cfdi" and "document" make no sense. XML namespaces are used to define XML Schemas. If you don't know immediately the right answer, you can use whatever you want.

Comment: Finally, after testing and testing, It works. I had to define two URI one  for `cfdi ` and other for `document`  as you said. Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 0):

I faced some issues with namespaces before, maybe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76876486/sap-simple-transformations-with-dynamic-namespaces/76882188#76882188) helps.

Here is a reference code. as you can see you must define the namespace and also use it as you defined it, ns1 here.

```
<tt:template>

<top_element
    xmlns:ns1="xsd/namespacesForBoxes"
    xmlns:ns2="xsd/namespacesForCartons"
    xmlns:ns3="xsd/namespacesForPallets">
  <tt:namespace name="ns1"/>
  <tt:namespace name="ns2"/>
  <tt:namespace name="ns3"/>

    <tt:cond s-check="not-initial(ref('.telegram.BOX_ID'))">
      <ns1:container>
        <tt:attribute name="box-id" value-ref=".telegram.BOX_ID"/>
      </ns1:container>
    </tt:cond>

    <tt:cond s-check="not-initial(ref('.telegram.CARTON_ID'))">
      <ns2:container>
        <tt:attribute name="carton-id" value-ref=".telegram.CARTON_ID"/>
      </ns2:container>
    </tt:cond>

    <tt:cond s-check="not-initial(ref('.telegram.PALLET_ID'))">
      <ns3:container>
        <tt:attribute name="pallet-id" value-ref=".telegram.PALLET_ID"/>
      </ns3:container>
    </tt:cond>


</top_element>
</tt:template>
```

It should look like this afterwards:

```
<top_element
xmlns:ns1="xsd/namespacesForBoxes"
xmlns:ns2="xsd/namespacesForCartons"
xmlns:ns3="xsd/namespacesForPallets">
  <ns1:container box-id="BOX"/>
  <ns2:container carton-id="CARTON"/>
  <ns3:container pallet-id="PALLET"/>
</top_element>
```

The "tt:cond" is just so that missing XML tags or tags in different order don't mess up your transformation.